# Defining and using bash functions in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, aws-codepipeline

I thought I could slightly improve readability of repetitive `sed` calls when inserting secrets into a file with AWS CodeBuild. I defined a bash function:

```
replaceConfig() { sed -i 's|{'$1'}|'${!1}'|' config.json; }
```

This can be called like so:

```
replaceConfig DB_PASSWORD
```

And this will replace all instances of the text `{DB_PASSWORD}` in config.json with the value held in secret environment variable `DB_PASSWORD`. Unfotunately, this does not work in CodeBuild. Inspecting the log file, I see:

```
[Container] 2020*07*31 15:44:40 Running command replaceConfig DB_USERNAME
*codebuild*output*tmp*script.sh: line 4: replaceConfig: command not found
```

I get the same error defining the bash function with the alternative syntax:

```
function replaceConfig { sed -i 's|{'$1'}|'${!1}'|' config.json; }
```

I have read that buildspec version 0.1 used a separate shell process for each command, which would have caused this problem, but I am using buildspec version 0.2, so these commands should be sharing the same shell.

Of course I can just stick with the repetitive sed calls, but am I correct in understanding that bash functions cannot be used in buildspec commands at all? Is there a better way to get these secrets into a configuration file?

```yaml
version: 0.2

run-as: root

env:
  shell: bash
  variables:
    AWS_REGION: us-east-2
  secrets-manager:
    DB_USERNAME: db-credentials:username
    DB_PASSWORD: db-credentials:password
    DB_HOST: db-credentials:host
....
phases:
  ....
  post_build:
    commands:
      - replaceConfig() { sed -i 's|{'$1'}|'${!1}'|' config.json; }
      - replaceConfig DB_USERNAME
      - replaceConfig DB_PASSWORD
      - replaceConfig DB_HOST
....
```

Comment: Welcome to DevOps.SE, Kyle.  This seems like a good idea to me.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work.  Have you tried contacting AWS support?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I use free tier, which as far as I know does not allow me to contact AWS support for this kind of issue. I will try posting in the AWS Developer Forums though.

Comment: Sidenote: using envsubst is easier than sed almost every time. `envsubst < config.json.tpl > config.json`. It substitutes env vars into a template file, simple one liner. We can also tell envsubst to only replace a set of specific var names if desired.
`envsubst` is installed by default since codebuild standard 2.0 iirc

Comment: @OnethingSimple Thanks for this. Although it's a sidenote to the "XY Problem" I asked about, it does solve my original problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bash functions (even when exported) are not preserved across `commands` steps. This is in contrast to exported env variables, so it seems AWS is doing some shenanigans behind the scenes to prevent it. I see two basic options to work around that:

1. Combine steps which need the function in a single step. E.g.

   ```yaml
   commands:
     - |
       replaceConfig() { sed -i 's|{'$1'}|'${!1}'|' config.json; }
       replaceConfig DB_USERNAME &&
         replaceConfig DB_PASSWORD &&
         replaceConfig DB_HOST
   ```
2. Source the file with the functions you need in every step. This may sound laborious, but can be automated via the `BASH_ENV` environment variable. E.g. let's say you put all the functions you need in a `codbuild-helper.bash` file in your project root, then you can do:

   ```yaml
   env:
     shell: bash
     variables:
       AWS_REGION: us-east-2
       BASH_ENV: "$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/codebuild-helper.bash"
     secrets-manager:
       DB_USERNAME: db-credentials:username
       DB_PASSWORD: db-credentials:password
       DB_HOST: db-credentials:host
   ....
   phases:
     ....
     post_build:
       commands:
         - replaceConfig DB_USERNAME
         - replaceConfig DB_PASSWORD
         - replaceConfig DB_HOST
   ....
   ```

   But since this file will be sourced in every step (regardless if it's needed or not) and even in bash scripts called along the way, you should take care to indeed only put function definitions in there.